# Choose which program(s) should be killed when out of RAM

Tags: windows-7, memory-management

I am looking for a Windows 7 program with which I could define an order of priority of which program(s) should be killed when out of RAM.

Comment: Just for clarification - you want to specify the programs, but don't care what percent of RAM they are using? I.e, a program on your list which takes 1% of RAM will be terminated, but a program not on the list taking 75% will be allowed to live?

Comment: @Mawg yes~~~~~~