# Monitor a process and kill it when it exceeds a given amount of RAM

Tags: windows, gratis, monitoring, task-management

There's a memory leak in VS2015's StandardCollector.Service.exe, which is acknowledged by Microsoft, but it won't be fixed until the next Service Pack.

So in the meantime I get a warning from Windows that memory is low and I find out it has exceeded 7 GB of RAM and I kill it. I'd like to be able to automate that.

Requirements:

- Works on Windows.
- Allows you to specify the process by executable path.
- Allows you to specify how much RAM it should exceed before being killed.
- Is free.

There's a similar (unanswered) question here - [Choose which program(s) should be killed when out of RAM](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23556/choose-which-programs-should-be-killed-when-out-of-ram), but it's different in that I don't want to wait until overall system memory becomes slow, I just want to monitor that process's RAM.

Also there is a [question in AskUbuntu that asks basically the same](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54747/automatically-kill-a-process-if-it-exceeds-a-given-amount-of-ram), but I need it for Windows, not for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to clear the working set instead of killing the process itself.

Use [EmptyWorkingSet()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms682606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to clear the RAM usage of an application or set its maximum value using [SetProcessWorkingSetSize()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms686234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I had a similar problem, you could extend [this program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637665/empty-working-set-from-cmd) which currently needs the process id instead of the executable path and put it in a loop to periodically clear the working set of the specified process id every 60s:

```
:loop
  mem_min 1234
  timeout 60
goto loop
```